# Javascript, conditional variable via function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to set a variable conditionally. It's basically to handle the first click user case - so I would like to set it conditionally based upon that. I instantiate a model which fetches the variable for me, but the first time the model has not been instantiated so the function i am calling gets a good ol' undefined is not a function. So what I'm trying is -

```
 var filterInstance = $scope.filterModel.getChecks() ? $scope.filterModel.getChecks() : {};
```

Basically I would like filterInstance to check $scope.filterModel.getChecks(), if it gets undefined is not a function, set it to an empty object, otherwise use $scope.filterModel.getChecks(). Could someone point me in the right direction here? Thanks!

Comment: `$scope.filterModel.getChecks()` makes a call to that function, or it tries to. If `.getChecks` is undefined that'll be an error. If you leave off the `()` however then it's just checking whether there's a "getChecks" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the property that references the function, without actually calling the function. This is done by removing the `()`.

```
var filterInstance = $scope.filterModel.getChecks ? $scope.filterModel.getChecks() : {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just doing:

```
var filterInstance = ($scope.filterModel.getChecks && $scope.filterModel.getChecks()) || {};
```

this way, if `$scope.filterModel.getChecks` exists and `$scope.filterModel.getChecks()` returns something "truthy", it is set in `filterInstance`, otherwise it is an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
 var filterInstance = $scope.filterModel.getChecks !== undefined ? $scope.filterModel.getChecks() : {};
```